# How to transform a row ["A, B, C", "7"] into three rows ["A", "7"], ["B", "7"], ["C", "7"]

Tags: r, string, split, tidyverse

Imagine the following table

| Elem | Freq |
| --- | --- |
| A | 14 |
| A, B | 7 |
| A, C | 8 |
| A, B, C | 1 |
| B, C | 3 |
| B | 11 |
| C | 6 |

How can I transform it in a table where I isolate each element and sum the frequency.

In this case would be

| Term | Freq |
| --- | --- |
| A | 30 |
| B | 22 |
| C | 18 |

I thought of write a enormous case_when (I have way more than three elements) to search the whole table and sum the freq of the rows they're present, but this is to much

I thought of break the lines like this:

| Elem | Freq |
| --- | --- |
| A | 14 |
| A | 7 |
| B | 7 |
| A | 8 |
| C | 8 |
| A | 1 |
| B | 1 |
| C | 1 |
| B | 3 |
| C | 3 |
| B | 11 |
| C | 6 |

And then group it an sum the freqs, but I don't know how

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try `separate_longer_delim` and then `summarise`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
    separate_longer_delim(Elem, ", ") %>%
    summarise(Freq = sum(Freq), .by = Elem)
```

and you will obtain

```
  Elem Freq
1    A   30
2    B   22
3    C   18
```

Comment: `separate_rows(Elem, sep=", ")` is also valid in this case.

Comment: @JilberUrbina Yes, that works well too :)

Comment: Thanks @ThomasIsCoding and @jilber-urbina!
That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Using `strsplit` and `xtabs`.

```
> Map(data.frame, strsplit(dat$Elem, ',\\s*'), dat$Freq) |> lapply(setNames, names(dat)) |> 
+   do.call(what='rbind') |> setNames(names(dat)) |> xtabs(Freq ~ Elem, data=_) |> as.data.frame()
  Elem Freq
1    A   30
2    B   22
3    C   18
```

Answer (score 2):

Another base R solution

```
> tmp <- stack(setNames(strsplit(df$Elem,', '), df$Freq)) 
> tmp[,"ind"] <- as.numeric(as.character(tmp[,"ind"]))
> aggregate(ind ~ values, FUN = sum, data = tmp)
  values ind
1      A  30
2      B  22
3      C  18
```

Data:

```
structure(list(Elem = c("A", "A, B", "A, C", "A, B, C", "B, C", 
"B", "C"), Freq = c(14L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 11L, 6L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```